# youtube api onPlayerStateChange not firing

Tags: youtube-api

i have looked through everything online and only see answers from a couple of years ago, and none of them help me. i see onYouTubeIframeAPIReady fire, but i never see onPlayerStateChange or onPlayerReady fire when the video plays or ends.

```
<iframe id="ytvideoframe1" width="100%" height="auto" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZHqBp9vbO5E?enablejsapi=1&origin=http://www.earluminator.com"frameborder="0" allowfullscreen ></iframe>    



<script>

var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
                console.log("onYouTubeIframeAPIReady");
        player = new YT.Player('ytvideoframe1', {
        playerVars: { 'controls': 0, 'modestbranding': 1, 'showinfo': 0 },
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
    console.log("player1 created - onYouTubeIframeAPIReady");

  }

  function onPlayerReady(event) {
                console.log("onPlayerReady");
        player = new YT.Player('ytvideoframe1', {
        playerVars: { 'controls': 0, 'modestbranding': 1, 'showinfo': 0 },
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
  }
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        console.log("onPlayerStateChange");
    if ((event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING ) ) {
        console.log("PLAYING");

    }
    if ((event.data == YT.PlayerState.PAUSED ) ) {
        console.log("PAUSED");

    }
    else  {
        console.log("OTHER");

    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `onPlayerReady` is not firing because as opposed to the suggested implementation [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference), your `onPlayerReady` is calling itself with the `onReady` event. Seems like you copied over the `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()` code and forgot to make changes. As mentioned in the documentation linked above, I would suggest to change your `onPlayerReady` implementation as shown

```
 // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
      }
```

Consequently, your `onPlayerStateChange` is not firing because according to your code, it is not getting there. Fixing your `onPlayerReady` should fix this problem as well.