# Youtube API - Determine if someone has started / finished watching a video

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

Regarding the [YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) -- Is possible to determine if someone has started to watch or finished watching a video?

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in the documentation [linked](http://%20%20https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) above, I would suggest to follow implementation as shown

```
   // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
  }

  // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
  //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
  //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
  var done = false;
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
      setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
      done = true;
    }
  }
```

Some more useful link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34127073/youtube-api-onplayerstatechange-not-firing) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29553570/youtube-api-onplayerstatechange) Hope it helps